# Double Router Forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

https://portforward.com/help/doublerouterportforwarding.htm

I have One internet connection set up with two routers for separate networks.

Internet is plugged into WAN on Router 1. Router 1 IP is 192.168.1.1

Router 2 - LAN port on Router 1 to WAN port on Router 2, IP is 192.168.2.1

Router 1 - DHCP Set to 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.249 (This is default for router)

Router 2 DHCP Set to 192.168.2.100 - 192.168.2.149

I need to forward ports 8080, 51423, 8096, 9091, 4040 on router 2.

So if I forward Router 1 (192.168.1.1) to router 2 (192.168.2.1) what port number(s) would I forward? In the above link it just says forward ports from Router 1 to Router 2 but it only mentions IP addresses not a port number.

Do I need to forward each port I need open on router 1 to router 2?

Example:

App Name "My App" | Ext port "8080" | Internal Port "8080" | Protocol "Type.for.App\UDP\TCP\BOTH?" | Device IP "192.168.2.1" (Router 2)

Or should I use DMZ? If DMZ:

```
    1.which router do I set it on Router 1 or Router 2?
    2. Source IP range (Router 1 IP address? 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.1?)
    3. Destination IP address (Router 2 address? 192.168.2.1?
```

I tried to set DMZ on Router 2 as described above but it says "unexpected 
error" (Everything I read about using DMZ set to set it on router 2)

I could probably figure this out by myself with some more research and some trial & error but I have limited access to router 1. So anything I need to change on router 1, I need to be able to get it right on the first try. As router 1 is my landlords and I don't have his password but he will input it for me and let me change what I need to, to get my stuff set up and running the way I need.

Thanks any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have four choices:

1. For every port that you want to forward from router 2 to its LAN, forward that port on router 1 from the WAN to router 2.
2. Put router 2 in router 1's DMZ.
3. Don't set up your routers to create two separate LANs.
4. Configure both LANs on the same router using a dual-LAN router.

Comment: Item 1.  In router 1, I set each port I need to forward to router 2 IP address or to IP address of the system I need the port forwarded for? (I'm using FreeNas with Jails so each Jail as its own IP address)                                                                                   Item 2. In router 1 under DMZ which IP address do I set as source and which IP address do I set as Destination. (Router 1 Source and Router 2 Destination)               Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: As the step says, you forward it from the WAN to router 2, so to router 2's IP address. I'm not sure what you're asking about putting router 2 in router 1`s DMZ. Are you asking how to configure the DMZ in router 1? Or how to configure router 2? Or something else?

Comment: Yes  I was asking correct configuration for DMZ in router 1. DMZ as two options source and destination. I was asking which IP is source and which IP is destination.

Comment: The source IP address should be any IP address. The destination IP address should be router 2's IP address on router 1's network. (What is router 2's IP address on router 1's LAN? It's not mentioned in your question.)

Comment: I will need to check when I have access to router 1. I have no way of checking at the moment. IP config /all and PFconfig only show me Router 1 IP address, Public IP Address, Router 2 IP Address & LAN IP Addresses from Router 2. I'm not sure how I can see LAN IP addresses from Router 1 without Access to Router 1. I'm sure I could plug Ethernet from Router 1 directly into my PC and get IP Addresses from Router 1 but I'm not sure it would assign the same IP address it assigned to router 2. Thank you for all your information I should be able to get it done from everything you described.

Comment: Edit* Router 2 WAN IP Address

Comment: @Thoth82 Router 2's WAN IP address is its address on router 1's LAN. That's the address you need to forward ports to or use as the destination in the DMZ configuration. Ideally, that would be a static IP address outside of router 1's DHCP range but inside its LAN range. For example, 192.168.1.252